# Google Analytics Easy Dashboard Library

Tags: google-analytics-api

I was trying to mess around with this new "easy" way to use google analytics API. Did not work for me even though I followed the instructions correctly. Anyone have any issues with this?

Try it out...

http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/reporting/javascript/ez-ga-dash/docs/user-documentation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another easy fix is to set up a button to actually call the render method, rather than having it execute instantly like the basic example. (last line, chained method)
- or a 3-5 second timeout

Or use the "cool demo" link for a better starting point code

Answer (score 0):

yes i tried it also and not worked.

It seems like i'm missing some library on my localhost. I've checked the scripts execution and when it does

if (gapi.client.analytics) {

it throws the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'analytics' of undefined
    this.renderFunction();

Regards

Answer (score 0):

While I was getting an undefined error, I changed code in line 220 as a temporary fix.
Know it loads perfectly. this is the code:

```
// If the client library has loaded.
if(typeof gapi.client != 'undefined'){ //new code
//if (gapi.client.analytics) {
```